# Как стилизовать отдельные элементы в json файле?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, sass

Всем привет, подскажите, как можно стилизовать отдельные элементы в json файле? Вот например у меня есть json файл, там такие элементы (прикрепил меньше, так как их гораздо больше):

```
 [
        {
          "id": 1,
          "categoryTitle": "Launching A Contest",
          "shortCategoryTitle": "launching",
          "faqs": [
            {
              "question": "How long does it take to start receiving submissions?",
              "answer": "For Naming contests, you will start receiving your submissions within few minutes of launching your contest. Since our creatives are located across the globe, you can expect to receive submissions 24 X 7 throughout the duration of the brainstorming phase."
            },
            {
              "question": "How long do NamingContests last?",
              "answer": "You can choose a duration from 1 day to 7 days. We recommend a duration of 3 Days or 5 Days. This allows for sufficient time for entry submission as well as brainstorming with creatives. If you take advantage of our validation services such as Audience Testing and Trademark Research, both will be an additional 4-7 days (3-5 business days for Audience Testing and 1-2 business days for Trademark Research)."
            },
            {
              "question": "Where are the creatives located?",
              "answer": "About 70% of our Creatives are located in the United States and other English speaking countries (i.e. United Kingdom, Canada, and Australia.). We utilize an advanced rating score algorithm to ensure that high quality creatives receive more opportunities to participate in our contests."
            },
            {
              "question": "What if I do not like any submissions?",
              "answer": "While it is unusually rare that you will not like any names provided, we have a few options in case this problem occurs: If the contest ends and you have not yet found a name that you’d like to move forward with, we can provide complimentary extension of your contest as well as a complimentary consultation with one of our branding consultants (a $99 value). By exploring our premium domain marketplace you can apply the contest award towards the purchase of any name listed for sale. If you choose the Gold package or Platinum package and keep the contest as \"Not Guaranteed\", you can request a partial refund if you choose not to move forward with any name from you project. (Please note that the refund is for the contest award). Here is a link to our Refund Policy"
            },
            {
              "question": "How much does it cost?",
              "answer": "Our naming competitions start at $299, and our logo design competitions start at $299. Also, there are three additional contest level that each offer more features and benefits. See our Pricing Page for details"
            },
            {
              "question": "I need both a Name and a Logo/ Do you offer any discount for multiple contests?",
              "answer": "Yes! We have many contest bundles - our most popular being our Name, Tagline, and Logo bundle. Bundles allow you to purchase multiple contests at one time and save as much as from $75 - $400. You can learn more about our bundle options on our Pricing Page."
            },
            {
              "question": "What if I want to keep my business idea private?",
              "answer": "You can select a Non Disclosure Agreement (NDA) option at the time of launching your competition. This will ensure that only those contestants who agree to the NDA will be able to read your project brief and participate in the contest. The contest details will be kept private from other users, as well as search engines."
            },
            {
              "question": "Can you serve customers outside the US?",
              "answer": "Absolutely. Squadhelp services organizations across the globe. Our customer come from many countries, such as the United States, Australia, Canada, Europe, India, and MENA. We’ve helped more than 25,000 customer around the world."
            },
            {
              "question": "Can I see any examples?",
              "answer": "Our creatives have submitted more than 6 Million names and thousands of logos on our platform. Here are some examples of Names, Taglines, and Logos that were submitted in recent contests."
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "id": 2,
          "categoryTitle": "Buying From Marketplace",
          "shortCategoryTitle": "buying",
          "faqs": [
            {
              "question": "What's included with a Domain Purchase?",
              "answer": "When you purchase a domain from our premium domain marketplace, you will receive the exact match .com URL, a complimentary logo design (along with all source files), as well as a complimentary Trademark report and Audience Testing if you’re interested in validating your name."
            },
            {
              "question": "How Does the Domain transfer process work?",
              "answer": "Once you purchase a Domain, our transfer specialists will reach out to you (typically on the same business day). In most cases we can transfer the domain to your preferred registrar (such as GoDaddy). Once we confirm the transfer details with you, the transfers are typically initiated to your account within 1 business day."
            },
            {
              "question": "If I purchase a Domain on installments, can I start using it to setup my website?",
              "answer": "We offer payment plans for many domains in our Marketplace. If you purchase a domain on a payment plan, we hold the domain in an Escrow account until it is fully paid off. However our team can assist you with making any changes to the domains (such as Nameserver changes), so that you can start using the domain right away after making your first installment payment."
            }
          ]
        },
    ]
```

Вот как можно стилизовать отдельно все элементы в id 1 и отдельно стилизовать все элементы в id 2?

А вот моя часть кода, но в ней стилизовано все элементы:

```js
 const faqCategories = (category, i) => (
        <div id={category.shortCategoryTitle} key={i}>
          <h3 className={styles.categoryTitle}>{category.categoryTitle}</h3>
          <div className={styles.faqs}>
            {category.faqs.map(faq => (
              <FAQ faq={faq} />
            ))}
          </div>
        </div>
      );


<section className={styles.sectionFour}>
                    <ul className={styles.categories}>
                        {categories.map((category, i) => (
                        <li key={i}>
                            <a href={`#${category.shortCategoryTitle}`}>
                            {category.categoryTitle}{' '}
                            </a>
                        </li>
                        ))}
                    </ul>
                    <div className={styles.FAQitems}>{categories.map(faqCategories)}</div>
                </section>
```

Comment: Ну проверяйте ваш `id` если он `===` не тому, что вам нужен - возвращайте `null`.

Comment: Используя данные стейта можно сформировать любую последовательность классов или любой набор css-свойств. Потом просто присвоить эти наборы/последовательности соответствующим html-элементам.

Comment: Не совсем понял. Вы хотите, что все элементы с id  = 1, были одного стиля, а с id = 2, другой стиль? Или вы хотите, чтобы четные имели другой стиль? Можете подробнее описать какого поведения вы ожидаете?

Comment: @SaNFeeD Да, смотрите, все элементы где id 1, тоесть categoryTitle,  shortCategoryTitle, faqs были одного стиля, а элементы categoryTitle,  shortCategoryTitle, faqs в id 2 были другого стиля. Просто если я делаю, что однаковые стили для всех элементов, то получается у меня все слитно и не могу нормально сделать отступы, мне надо стилизиовать именно те элементы, которые идут после id 1.

Comment: @AndrewPhoenix. А как вы добавляете стили?

Comment: @SaNFeeD А там я выше прикрепил часть кода